# ValueError with Pandas - shaped of passed values

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I'm trying to use Pandas and PyODBC to pull from a SQL Server View and dump the contents to an excel file.

However, I'm getting the error when dumping the data frame (I can print the colums and dataframe content):

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 228), indices imply (2, 228)
```

There are several other issues on this forum pertaining to the same issue, but none discuss pulling from a SQL Server table.

I can't figure out what is causing this error, and altering the view to cast the source columns differently has no effect.

Here is the python code i'm using:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=servername;DATABASE=dbname;UID=username;PWD=password')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
script = """
SELECT * FROM schema.ActiveEnrollmentCount
"""
cursor.execute(script)
columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]

data = cursor.fetchall()

df = pd.DataFrame(list(data), columns=columns)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('c:\temp\ActiveEnrollment.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='bar')

writer.save()
```

The 2 columns I'm trying to pull are both 3-digit integers.

Comment: Just to be clear, where is this error coming from? Pulling from the table or dumping the dataframe?

Comment: (side note: you should `import pandas as pd`, like most people, so that can reuse and share snippets of code)

Comment: Another note: you should better use `df = pd.read_sql_query(script, cnxn)` instead of doing the execute and converting to dataframe manually

Comment: @NBartley updated my answer - it's happening when dumping the dataframe. Thanks!

Comment: @JulienMarrec thanks! I grabbed this sample from another stackoverflow post...

Comment: Can you give a small sample of your dataframe that still fails when dumping so we can recreate the issue?
Also what version of Python and Pandas are you using?

Comment: @joris has the answer - switching to f = pd.read_sql_query(script, cnxn) solved the issue! Please add as an answer and I will accept. Thank you all for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To query data from a database, you can better use the built-in [`read_sql_query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html) function instead of doing the execute and converting to dataframe manually.
For your example, this would give something like:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(script, cnxn)
```

See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries) for more explanation on `read_sql`/`to_sql`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked from to export data from sqlserver to excel sheet .

```
import pyodbc
    import pandas as pd
    from openpyxl import Workbook


    cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                          "Server=WINS2012;"
                          "Database=NameOfDataBase;"
                          "Trusted_Connection=yes;")


    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    script = """
    SELECT * FROM ims_employee
    """
    cursor.execute(script)

    columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]

    data = cursor.fetchall()

    df = pd.read_sql_query(script, cnxn)

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\SqlExcel\Book1.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='bar')

    writer.save()
```

Comment: This worked for me by taking help from the above examples